# Dell Dimension 9200 Bottleneck

Tags: performance, gaming, nvidia-graphics-card

I just recently gotten a used Dell Dimension 9200. I am using it for gaming. The problem I am having is when playing games like GTA IV,etc they tend to lag/slow down in performance. I am wondering if it could be bottlenecks in the machine causing this problem. I'm not sure if that is a bottleneck or issue with the games I am running. If its bottlenecks, would it be with my PSU or graphics card?

Here is my Dell Dimension 9200 Specs. Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit Operating System. Intel Core 2 Quad cpu Q6700 model with a clock speed 2.66GHz and 8 MB L2 Cache. 8 GB of DDR2 ram at a clock speed of 800 MHz. **Gigabyte GeForce GT 630 2GB DDR3** PCI Express 2.0 card. Western Digital 320 GB 7200 rpm hard drive A 375 Watt Dell PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GeForce GT 630 2GB DDR3 is not a good gaming card. The chip is too slow and the RAM is only DDR3 which is also slower comapred to GDDR5 which better cards use.

According to the list, the card is slower than 5-6 years old cards.

http://www.pc-erfahrung.de/grafikkarte/vga-grafikrangliste.html